# Gource on mac crashing

Tags: macos, homebrew, gource

I have installed brew and gource and I have uninstalled and re installed but when I run it it crashes with gource stopped unexpectedly. I know this is meant to install and run out the box as I have seen it work with windows machines.

I get Segmentation fault: 11 as the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem and found this issue in the repo: [segmentation fault (home-brew)](https://github.com/acaudwell/Gource/issues/51).

After running `brew update && brew upgrade`, gource ran as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Although it didn't help for me, perhaps the solution described in this ticket could solve it for you:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/gource/issues/207

Comment: I ran it on a single screen and I updated and reinstalled still getting the same error.

Comment: Had the same issue here. Seems to be broken on EL Capitan